# Handling Early Arriving Facts or Inferred Members in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have been working on an `SSIS` solution which would handle the early arriving facts into a dimension with no luck so far. Supposedly, table Loyalty Scheme is related to Partition table and Company table. In the transaction, loyalty scheme ID is NULL with Partition 1 and Company 1 then i'd have to insert the below inferred member in the `LoyaltyScheme` table to avoid lookup failure.

```
'N/A', 'Partition 1', 'Company 1'
```

Currently i am inserting inferred members manually which is hectic. Could anyone please help me with a script so that any lookup failure leads to inserting an inferred member into that table and also returning surrogate key of that record?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow what you are saying. Do you think you can try to clarify?

Comment: Staging tables are your friends.  This situation is trivial if you use them.

Comment: Zane, The lookup task in my SSIS package fails because of no match. I want to use a script task which can insert the no-match row first in the table and then return the key so that lookup tasks doesn't fail.

Answer (score 1):

Load your incoming "fact table" data into a staging table first.  Then, run an insert query to add the new records to your dimension table.

```
insert into dimension
(name)
select name 
from staging
where name in 
(select name
from staging
except 
select name 
from dimension)
```

Then update your staging table from your dimension table.

```
update staging
set dimensionId = dimension.dimensionId
from staqing join dimension on staging.name = dimension.name
```

Now you can insert records from your staging table to your fact table.